# multitouch in Processing Java/Python

Tags: python, java, processing

I'm new to Processing and I'd like to develop a touchscreen based effects app. It will be used to display cool effects on an LED matrix table I'm building.

now my question is whether Python or Java processing have the capability to handle multitouch, and how?

I tried using p5.js but a browser environment is not suitable for what I'm trying to do, in addition to being too slow (where straight lines between points form instead of smooth tracking because of update frequency)

dearest regards,
Pol.

Comment: so it's a DIY multitouch table you're using, using bottom to top camera or a different system ? (How does the table generate the multitouch data) ?

Comment: @GeorgeProfenza I'll be using a big IR screen overlay frame

Comment: It depends what you use to process the IR data and spit out tracking points. If it's all done in Processing it's all up how you structure the data (probably an `int` ID and `PVector` for position ?). If you use an external tool/Python script hopefully you can send the data out via OSC (TUIO maybe?) or WebSockets then use Processing as a client receiving this data. Doing a quick search will reveal libraries like https://github.com/HCI-Lab-Saarland/MultiTouchKitUI or https://github.com/vialab/SMT but in your case, since it's DIY it really depends what generates the touch data, right ?

Comment: My overlay frame has a USB connection, so I'm going to assume it imitates a touchpad as most os's don't have support for multiple mouse pointers.

Comment: Does your overlay frame have documentation for the communication protocol ? (e.g. does it have a driver that exposes it as a USB HID device, is a Serial port which needs data to be parsed, etc.). This will determine wether you can use an existing Processing library or wether you need to manually handle communication.

Comment: As I said, it gets exposed as a USB HID device. It won't be any different to a touchscreen on a laptop per say. There might be a possibility to intercept serial data but if possible I'd like to avoid it for simplicity and ease of installation.

Comment: My bad: I missed where you explicitly mentioned it's an USB HID device. Try the https://github.com/vialab/SMT library. Let's say you're on Windows and the device you use implements Windows Touch then it **should** work. It's all guess workout without knowing what OS you use, a datasheet/manual of the multitouch device etc, but it sounds like you've got all that under control. It would be nice if you post the answer once you successfully tested your setup. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks! I'll try my best to het it working. Otherwise I might have to step off of processing and look into QT or something similar.